# Stopped at a breakpoint, export the values ​of the STM32Fx microcontroller registers to TXT

Tags: stm32cubeide

Contextualizing:

I am working on a project and to do some analysis I saw that it is interesting to compare the values ​​of the registers of the project versions after stopping at a breakpoint, such as GPIOA/B, TIMx, NVIC, DMA1, ADC, etc.

The project code is versioned with GIT and so I can switch between versions. There is the old stable version and the new version with the modifications I'm working on.

So...

**I would like to arrive at a certain point in the code execution and export all the values ​​of the registers to a TXT, both from the stable version and from the version under development. I'm doing this task manually, taking printscreen and comparing.**

*The CUBE IDE's SFR tool displays updated values ​​when it stops at a breakpoint, however unfortunately it does not have the possibility to export to a text file.*

Comment: maybe this tool has capacity, but it is not possible to aggregate in the CUBE IDE:
https://github.com/1udo6arre/svd-tools

Comment: Possibility 1: Add the registers of interest to the "Expressions" view (the watch window). Example: Add `*(unsigned *)0x41234000` to display a 32-bit register at address 0x41234000. Unlike the SFR window, you can copy the content of the "Expressions" view to the clipboard and paste it to a text file.

Comment: Possibility 2: In our company, we developed Eclipse plug-ins and install them to STM32CubeIDE. (Because STM32CubeIDE uses an old Java version internally, the plug-ins must be compiled accordingly.) Unfortunately, developing a simple plug-in takes about one day for a skilled Java programmer...

Comment: If you use Possibility 1: Eclipse (STM32CubeIDE) saves the list of expressions in the "Expressions" view in some XML file. You may add one or two registers, exit the STM32CubeIDE and find out which XML file contains the registers you added. Then you can add all registers you are interested in to the XML file in a text editor (or even semi-automatically using some script writing to the XML file). Then you re-start the STM32CubeIDE again.

Answer (score 0):

STM32CubeProgrammer allows you to export all peripheral values with adress and bit extraction. It is still in BETA version in v2.13.0 but it is fully working for my STM32H753 usage.

> Peripheral :Cache Name    Value   Access  Address
> CLIDR 0x09000003  read-only   @ 0xE000ED78
> LoUU 0x1
> LoC  0x1
> LoUIS    0x0
> CL7   0x0
> CL6   0x0  CL5    0x0  CL4    0x0  CL3    0x0  CL2    0x0  CL1    0x3
> [...]